# How can I find all for-loops in a Java file using javaparser?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I am using [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) to parse a Java file and I would like to find all occurrences of `for` loops (`forEach` & normal `for` loops). This is my approach so far, but it only finds some, not all occurrences.

```
public class AstElementTraverser extends VoidVisitorAdapter<File> { 
    @Override
    public void visit(ForeachStmt n, File sourceFile) {
        System.out.println("Found a foreach loop " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " @ " + n.getBeginLine());
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(ForStmt n, File sourceFile) {
        System.out.println("Found a for loop " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " @ " + n.getBeginLine());
    }
}
```

For instance, it seems to work for this line:

```
for (final JavadocTagInfo tag : JavadocTagInfo.values()) {
```

... but not for this:

```
for (PropertyDescriptor<?> descriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
```

... nor this one:

```
for (int i = 1; i < typeCodes.length; i++) {
```

Is this a possible bug in javaparser, or am I just using it the wrong way?

Comment: `but it just finds a small amount`. When does it work? When does it not work?

Comment: It only finds one currently: `for (final JavadocTagInfo tag : JavadocTagInfo.values()) {` and examples for one not found are `for (PropertyDescriptor<?> descriptor : propertyDescriptors) {` and `for (int i = 1; i < typeCodes.length; i++) {`

Comment: Please add this information to your question.

Comment: I honestly don't know what I might add to specify the question. Should I share a Github link?

Comment: Daniel, I took the liberty of adding the examples from your comments to the question. That's what @Chetan was referring to when he asked you to "add this information to the question". This way, it is easier for people reading the question to get an understanding of what works and what doesn't, without having to look through the comments.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Thank you, I didn't get it.

Comment: It seems a bug to me, it would be great if you could open an issue at https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser Thanks!